# KDE daemon asks for disk password on every login

Tags: kde, dolphin

I installed Manjaro KDE edition a couple days ago. I opened Dolphin and in the Devices section I accessed a Windows drive from which I copied some files. The drive is protected by Bitlocker. Now whenever I log in I get the following dialog:

[image: Disk password dialog]

> WDC WD30PURX-64P6ZY0 needs a password to be accessed. Please enter a password

How do I get rid of that prompt? What I tried so far:

- I opened the drive and enabled showing hidden files to check if some utility is creating files there when unlocked. I didn't find anything, only some Microsoft directories ($RECYCLE.BIN, msdownld.tmp, System Volume Information)
- I removed the drive from Dolphin's "Recent Locations" section. This turned out surprisingly hard to achieve, I ended up using the query from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1555756/kde-recent-documents-only-not-locations), but it still didn't help.
- I temporarily uninstalled Dolphin, logged out and back in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *System Settings* and go to *Removable Storage* → *Removable Devices* where the device should be listed, select it and use the *Forget Device* button to stop KDE from trying to mount it on login.

[image]

Note: The UI behaves a little bit strange for me, I had to disconnect the device first, uncheck the *On Login* and *On Attach* options for *All Known Devices* first to be able to use the *Forget Device* button.

Comment: Thank you, that's the screen I needed. I just ended up unchecking On Login and On Attach instead of clicking Forget Device.

Comment: Great help, thanks a lot! PS: Windows drive cannot be disconnected, so it always appears under "Attached Devices" and cannot be forget. Just remove the checkmarks from "All known devices" and from the windows partition.